# Proper A/C BTUs for Apartment

Tags: air-conditioning

According to [this energystar.gov chart](https://www.energystar.gov/products/heating_cooling/air_conditioning_room?qt-consumers_product_tab=2#qt-consumers_product_tab), the proper air conditioning BTU capacity for a 500 square foot room is 12,000 BTUs.

However, since this is an apartment divided up into several rooms with the possibility of only one A/C unit, *I was wondering if 12,000 BTUs is still the correct capacity.*

Here is a diagram of the apartment. The location of the A/C unit is indicated. The unit is a window style unit mounted into a wall:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: How will the cool air get to the rest of the apartment?

Comment: @DanielGriscom That's been a challenge with the current 20 year old unit rated at 5,000 BTUs. The bedroom seems to take the longest to cool due to its location.

Comment: If a 5k BTU unit does an even slightly passable job, then a 12k BTU unit will have plenty of capacity.